# USB SSD is not recognized

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I've got a new USB SSD drive, A-Data SC685. Works OOTB on mac and windows 10. Windows laptop has dual-boot with ubuntu 18.04 and it doesn't work there.

dmesg output:

```
[  124.619393] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  124.646145] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  124.649614] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  124.665346] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  125.664854] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMICRON  JMS580                PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  125.666148] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  125.668916] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[  125.668922] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  125.668925] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[  125.672237] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  125.672242] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  125.672245] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[  125.672252] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  125.672254] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[  125.672436] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  125.672439] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  125.672611] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[  125.672618] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  125.680230] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[  125.680235] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  125.680238] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[  125.681801] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  125.681807] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  125.681810] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[  125.682405] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

lsblk:

```
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0         0 disk
```

What's going on? Any ideas how to fix this w/o upgrading ubuntu?

Comment: Have you used it in any Windows with the default Fast Startup feature enabled? If so then you probably need to boot Windows with that drive connected, disable Fast Startup and shutdown.

Comment: No, just formatted it on Mac

Comment: What file system have you formatted it with? Typical ones of MacOS have no native support and MacOS has no native support for EXT or NTFS so... I think you get the picture

Comment: lsblk shows it as 0 size, it's not an FS issue. I tried with exfat and fat, I'd try ext4 if it was only possible to get block device working. To be clear – I can't even DD to /dev/sda

Comment: We still don't know what file system that is...

Comment: exfat. There’s one more fact that’s as important as file system on a block device that’s not properly recognized/initiated: ssd color. It’s white.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 had no support for exFAT therefore requiring the installation of exfat-fuse and exfat-utils

Comment: Now now, don't be rude @hryamzik - if you're getting frustrated, take a break, and go take a walk for a bit.  (Comments are locked for an hour to let things cool down)